# Best Database to use for iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, database, cocoa, core-data

I am trying to develop an iOS app (Swift) that requires the use of database. The app will have three different users login and courses. I have 5 database tables that i will have in my app but I am not sure which database platform to use. (I have done research and some people recommend Core data and others say Realm)Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Local or remote?

Comment: Im not sure. Im new to this :)

Comment: You need to do more research first to understand what the requirements are and what kind of persistence solution you need.

Answer (score 2):

Depend upon your requirement you need to choose Realm, Sqlite and CoreData database.

For Reference check this link

https://rollout.io/blog/ios-databases-sqllite-core-data-realm/

Answer (score 2):

Since you are just getting started, I would suggest you to try out CoreData and see if it works for your use case. It is object oriented, works well across all Apple platforms and is well integrated with Xcode. Although, please note that this only works for local data. However, if you need (or wish) to store the data on remote server then Firebase would be the way to go. Also this might be preferable if you later wish to do analytics based on the data stored.

Both of these work pretty well and aren't exactly comparable to each other coz they have different purpose. You just need to figure out what's your long term use case and plan it out. For more details check this: https://www.quora.com/How-does-Firebase-compare-to-Core-Data

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase if you do not want to setup your own database. You can then assign 'roles' to the users logging in. Check out Firebase authentication documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it locally, Core Data is fine.
But if you're doing it remotely (over the Internet, in the cloud), then Firebase is OK.